# Android:facebook audience network ads request always failed

Tags: android, ads, facebook-audience-network, banner-ads

I integrated Android FAN v4.24.0 SDK as docs says for testing live ads,but I found when first time to call "adView.loadAd()"(adView is a Adview Object), always received error 1001:" No fill,We are not able to serve ads to this person. Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a12. If you are integrating Audience Network for the first time, you can use test ads https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing.", then I called "adView.loadAd()" again, ad was filled. What's happening and how to avoid this issue? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your Facebook SDK to [v4.25.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x#4_25_0_audience_network_fixed).

> Fixed
>
> - Fixed no fill on the very first impression when advertising id hasn't been retrieved yet

Answer (score 0):

I was trying with SDK version v4.20.0, v4.24.0 . But I was getting failed again and again. 
After using **SDK v4.25.0** all ads are being shown.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.25.0'
```